# NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL timeout?

Tags: cocoa, httpwebrequest, timeout, nsurl

I writed a simple code to get string value from a web server, now I wanna to set timeout, like, do getData 10 sec then if server not responding after 10 second cancel getting data and do "noConnect". any idea how can I do that?

```
-(void)getData {
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:
@"http://exaple.com/example.plist"]];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *aKey  = [chamUpdateData objectForKey:@"count"];
}
-(void)noConnect{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the call to `dictionaryWith...` in an [`NSOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) in order to execute it asynchronously; then start an `NSTimer` so that then it fires, you can check the status of the `NSOperation`; if it is still `running`, then you cancel it.

Keep in mind that there is no way I know of to actually stop the network request, once you have sent it. So, you simply have a timeout to manage the case when the connection takes longer than that. If the response arrives in 1 minute, you will simply ignore that data.

Answer (score 0):

Create an NSTimer of 10 seconds and call the function which will check whether server is not responding or not and accordingly stop getting data.

> NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
>   target:self selector:@selector(stopGettingData) userInfo:nil
>   repeats:NO];

If the application is in cocos2d then you can not use NSTimer. Instead schedule a function with an interval of 1 second and just increment a count in that function and check if it is 10 in the same, and if count is 10 then call your stopGettingData function.